# Picture tag behave like a div

Tags: html, css

I need help to understand one thing: a picture tag behaves like a container for an img tag if its parent has 'display: flex'.
If I add width:50% to img, it doesn't make img 50% of div but make img 50% of picture. If I add width:50% to picture and width: 100% to img it works as I need.
But why do I need to add style to the picture to make img 50% of div? I thought that picture is just an invisible wrap to keep sources. But it behaves like a div. Why?

```
<div style="display: flex;">
    <picture style="width: 50%">
        <source srcset="img/cmn/logo.webp" type="image/webp">
        <img src="image.png" alt="img" style="width: 100%;">
    </picture>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From t[he specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-picture-element)

> The picture element is a **container** which provides multiple sources to its **contained** img element

So yes, it behaves like a div for the image and in your case the picture is the flex item (not the image)

Answer (score 2):

When using a `<picture>` element, it effectively takes over as the principal element of its content, the content becomes dependencies of the picture element. So how this works is expected.

You now work with the **picture** element and not with the individual image element(s) inside of it. This means you have to scale the **picture** element and not anything inside of it.

That said, it's common practice in responsive web design to always have `img` elements fill the full width of their parent container (width: 100%;), for responsiveness to become easier to handle and more predictable.

Authoritative information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture